# From correlated random variables to uncorrelated random variables

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $(X,Y)$ gaussian vector with $Cov(X,Y)=\rho$. Let $(x,y)$ a row-vector. Let $\Sigma$ be the correlation matrix. I know that the multivariate distribution function is (less the costant):

$$\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left((x-m_x,y-m_y)\cdot \Sigma^{-1}\cdot(x-m_x,y-m_y)^T\right)\right)$$

Let be $M$ the matrix of the eigevector normalized. So $M^TM=1$. In this way i can write:

$$\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left((x-m_x,y-m_y)\cdot(MM^T)\cdot \Sigma^{-1}\cdot (MM^T)\cdot(x-m_x,y-m_y)^T\right)\right)$$
and so:

$$\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\left(((x-m_x,y-m_y)\cdot M\big)\Lambda^{-1}\big(M^T\cdot(x-m_x,y-m_y)^T\big)\right)\Big)$$

I want something, or similar, such that i have:

$$\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left((\bar x-\bar m_x,\bar y- \bar m_y)\cdot \Lambda^{-1}\cdot(\bar x- \bar m_x,\bar y-\bar m_y)^T\right)\right)$$

such that when I'll do the integral i can split in two different part. Is it possible?

Comment: What integral (variable ranges) are you looking for?

Comment: the integral that have to compute is $\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} e^x(e^y-k)\chi_{(e^y-k>0)}f(x,y)dxdy$ where $\chi_A$ is the charateristic function of $A$ and $k$ positive constant.

Comment: Define a  linear tansformation on (X,Y) to (X',Y') so that Cov(X',Y')=0.